# Css transition manifests only inside timeout function

Tags: javascript, css, transition

I've created new div using JavaScript and set its width and height. Immediately after that I need to resize it to 100% width with transition effect. But it manifests only when the styles editing is inside of Timeout function. Without that it just jump to new width.

Css:

```
#project-detail {
  @extend .project-detail-preview;
  transition: width 0.25s ease-out, top 0.25s ease-out, left 0.25s ease-out, height 0.25s ease-out;
}
```

Script:

```
  var detailContainer = document.createElement("div");
  detailContainer.id = "project-detail";
  detailContainer.innerHTML = previewContent.innerHTML;
  detailContainer.style.width = previewWidth;
  detailContainer.style.height = previewHeight;

  blocksContainer.appendChild(detailContainer);

  for (let project of source.projects) {
    if(project.id == projectID) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        detailContainer.style.width = "100%";
      }, 1);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is because you append the div to the DOM, and immediately (next line of code), you resize it to 100% width.

The problem is that in the page's life cycle, the CSS doesn't have time to catch up and apply between these two lines of code. So, the transition duration is not yet applied, and you already resize the div, so it jumps immediately to 100%.

On the other hand, when you set a Timeout, being asynchronous, the function inside the Timeout is executed at the end of the execution stack, that is, after applying the CSS rules to the newly created elements. You can even set a 0 delay or no delay at all, it will work all the same.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation! It took me about four hours before I accidentally found this solution.. Now at least I know how it works :)

Answer (score 1):

JS is single threaded if you change width to 20 and then to 100, the change to 20 is like if didn't happen. so you need to use a setTimeout() so it first changes it to 20, and "later" it changes to 100

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do things like this with JS, even read bunch of articles about [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame) and understood, that things like that better to do with CSS classes. Try to toggle class on action:

```
for (let project of source.projects) {
    if(project.id == projectID) {
      detailContainer.className += ' fullwidth-class';
    }
}
```

And add same CSS class:

```
.fullwidth-class {
    width: 100%!important;
}
#project-detail {
    animation-duration: 1s;
}
```